# Internally, how does relay cache pagination for subqueries?

Tags: relayjs

Let's say I have a blog:

- 1 blog has many posts
- 1 post has many likers
- 1 post has many comments
- 1 comment has many likers

On the front page of my blog, I'd like to show the top 10 posts. For each post, I'd like to show the 10 most recent likers, the 5 most recent comments, and the 10 most recent people who liked each comment. (Numbers aren't important, I'm just setting up something similar to facebook).

So my query might look something like this:

```
query getPosts(
  $postCount: Int, 
  $likersCount: Int, 
  $commentCount: Int, 
  $commentCursor: ID,
  $commentLikersCount: Int) {
  recentPosts(first: $postCount) {
    id,
    title, 
    body,
    likers(first: $likersCount) {
      id,
      name
    },
    comments(first: $commentCount, after: $commentCursor) {
      id,
      title,
      body,
      likers(first: $commentLikersCount) {
        id,
        name
      },
    }
  }
}
```

If I resubmit this query with a new `$commentCursor` to load more comments, how does relay cache the data so it knows to grab everything else locally? I get the basic graph architecture of the store, but for nested things like this I get confused in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would extend the paginated range by changing the `first: $commentCount` argument, and you wouldn't use the `after` argument. Just say you change `$commentCount` from `5` to `10`, Relay knows to get the the items at positions 6 through 10, as it already has the ones from 1 through 5. Specifically, you'll see it issue an `first: 5, after: <cursor>` query, where `<cursor>` is the cursor of the 5th comment (Relay will automatically get cursors for every edge in the connection for this purpose, even if you don't ask for them explicitly).